# How can I check if the cursor is hovering on an element using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

It possible to check if the cursor is hovering on an element.

Something like

```
 $("#divId").is("hover");
```

NOTE: I just want to check not set event.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
.is(':hover');
```

or

```
$('#divId:hover');
```

Comment: Then use `if ($(selector:hover).length) { //dostuff }`

Comment: As of jQuery 1.6.4 it doesn't work in ie and, looking at api.jquery.com, isn't documented

Comment: Using the `:hover` as part of the initial selector didn't work for me in old versions of IE. Using `is(":hover")` didn't work in any browser. `is("hover")` worked in all browsers at the time of writing this.

Answer (score 4):

***Updated answer!***

```
$("#foo").hover(function() {
    $(this).data("hovered", true);
}, function() {
    $(this).data("hovered", false);
});
```

Testing if it is hovered...

```
if ( $("#foo").data("hovered") ) {
    // it is hovered
} else {
    // it's not hovered
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just store `hover=yes` on mouseenter and `hover=no` on mouseleave? That'd work no matter how long one hovers.

Comment: @Peter Where did your answer go? I was just testing your solution and it seems to work...

Answer (score 3):

You can use jQuery's **[`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/)**, **[`mouseenter()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/)** or **[`mouseover()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/)**

```
$("#divId").hover(function() { alert("hovering"; });
```

This will fire on mouseenter and mouseleave. You can add separate event handlers for each.

So if you want to do something like, `if hovering over #divId increase x by one, and when you stop hovering decrease y by one`:

```
$("#divId").hover(function() { ++x; }, 
                  function() { --y; });
```

---

If you really want an `if hovering`:

```
var hovering = 0;
$("#divId").hover(function() { hovering = 1; },
                  function() { hovering = 0; });
...
// Then inside somewhere useful. Maybe in a setInterval, or triggered by
//    another action...
if (hovering) { ...
```

### **[Try it out with this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TDVQL/)**

For example:

```
$(function() {
    var hovering = 0;
    $("div").hover(function() { hovering = 1; },
                   function() { hovering = 0; });

    $(document).keyup(function() {
         if (hovering) alert("hovering!");     // This is the "if hovering"
         else          alert("not hovering.");
    });
});
```

Comment: @Mark - Well that's the base. I added in an option.

Comment: No, it isn't. It just alerts whenever the visitor is hovering. The OP needs to do a check like in: `if ( hovering? ) { do one thing; } else { do another thing; }`

Comment: That seems to work, however it seems that @GetFresh's answer is the "ultimate" solution, since it doesn't require any hover() binding...

Answer (score 2):

You can use [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/). It's can be used like so:

```
$("selector").hover(
    function (){
        //mouse over
    },
    function (){
       //mouse out
    }
);
```

An example of it's use from the documentation is here:

```
$("li").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).append($("<span> ***</span>"));
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).find("span:last").remove();
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are doing either `mouseover()` (http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) or `hover()` (http://api.jquery.com/hover/) can be useful.