# Drop down menu disappearing before I can get to the links

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I possibly delay the disappearance of the menu by some miliseconds/seconds? 
going ahead and editing this `fadesettings: {overduration: 350, outduration: 2000}`in the js only changes the animation speed. But THAT IS NOT what I want =).

Please check [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SgyeB/) to see the JS, CSS, and HTML.

Thanks for the help guys

P.S:- about the top:80px gap that you see, I intentionally put it there cuz that's the way I'm styling my site so I want the gap there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can user the [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) function to add a delay before you call a function.

In your case, if you want to delay the fadeout of the menu, instead of just doing :

```
$this.children("ul:eq(0)").fadeOut(jquerycssmenu.fadesettings.outduration);
```

You could do

```
setTimeout(function() { $this.children("ul:eq(0)").fadeOut(jquerycssmenu.fadesettings.outduration)
}, 2000);
```

to delay the call by 2 seconds.

Note that I cached the $(this) selector in your fiddle to still be able to access the variable.

http://jsfiddle.net/KB5Ve/

EDIT : 
Added comments on the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/DBvq7/

Comment: I'm a little confused. Can you please add a comment to the code so I'll know where you added the new script please? :(

Comment: I added a couple of comments in the new fiddle which you can find here : http://jsfiddle.net/DBvq7/

Comment: but the menu disappears after the setTimeOut is reached. just look at this example for instance:- http://jsfiddle.net/KB5Ve/1/; the menu disappears whiles you're hovering. I set the time to 200 cuz I dont want the nav to stay for a long time

Comment: Then you have to test if you are hovering over the child elements. This answer shows how : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150358/how-can-i-check-if-the-cursor-is-hovering-on-an-element-using-jquery
However, unless you are doing it to learn, there is really no reason to code a menu from scratch like that, there are tons of menus out there that will do what you are looking for just fine.

Comment: Here is an example of a menu : http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#examples you can just style it to add your 80px padding

Comment: the reason I dislike superfish is that it messes up in IE7 on the z-indexing stuff. I've still not found a fix yet. Anyother dropdown you can recommend? Thanks though for your help man

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15402/discussion-between-hugo-migneron-and-santy)